# Using List to create lists of strings: difference(s) between two one-line codes?

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

In the *Virtual Book* of Mathematica, there is a simple example to show how to create lists of strings by `List`:

```
List[{"a", "b", "c"}, {"you", "are", "good"}]
```

here `" "` indicates these strings, which is easy to understand.

However, if we use

```
List[{a, b, c}, {you, are, good}]
```

instead, we can find that both codes give the same result:

> {{a, b, c}, {you, are, good}}

So my questions:

1. Whether or not the two codes are different with respect to the output of their results. If yes, what is(are) the difference(s)?
2. Whether or not the two codes are exactly the same in the context of a program?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Move your cursor into the output cell and type something to reveal the quotes. Mathematica hides quotes in outputs by default (I don't know why)

Comment: Your first List creates a list of strings, the second a list of actual undefined variables

Comment: Output cells, you see the results in, have `ShowStringCharacters->False` so no, they are not the same. Take a loot at `FullForm`. p.s. `List[1]` vs `{1}` is only a syntactic sugar, again compare with `FullForm`.

Comment: With respect to question 2, if you're ever wondering if two things are precisely identical in _Mathematica_, `SameQ` (`===`) works for that.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks a lot. Could you suggest how do I see that output cells have the property of `ShowStringCharacters->False`?

Comment: @Szabolcs Could you show an example please ? I guess you meant the same thing as Kuba. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

With

```
l1 = List[{"a", "b", "c"}, {"you", "are", "good"}];
l2 = List[{a, b, c}, {you, are, good}];
```

> *1. Whether or not the two codes are different with respect to the output of their results. If yes, what is(are) the difference(s)?*

One way to see that they are different is the following:

```
l1 // FullForm
l2 // FullForm
```

> [image: l1]

> [image: l2]

> Addressing the comment: *Could you suggest how do I see that output cells have the property of ShowStringCharacters->False*

From the [**`docs`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ShowStringCharacters.html?v=13.2) we read:

```
ShowStringCharacters is an option for Cell that specifies whether to display " when a string is entered.
```

So, you can set it to `True` for both lists and check for which one you will get the `""` like so:

```
ExpressionCell[l1, "Output", ShowStringCharacters -> True]
ExpressionCell[l2, "Output", ShowStringCharacters -> True]
```

> [image: out1]

> [image: out2]

> *2.Whether or not the two codes are exactly the same in the context of a program?*

When you run

```
l1 === l2
```

you get

> [image: false]